# Does **object** refer to group of materials in a specified structure here?

Tags: acoustics

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(acoustics)), Acoustic absorption refers to

> the process by which a material, structure, or **object** takes in sound energy when sound waves are encountered, as opposed to reflecting the energy. Part of the absorbed energy is transformed into heat and part is transmitted through the absorbing body. The energy transformed into heat is said to have been 'lost'.

Does **object** refer to group of materials in a specified structure here?

Comment: no, any kind of object

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not, the object could be a house, a person, a tree and so on, composed of one or several materials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it just a generic explanation or physical definition?

Comment: It is a generic explanation, most probably in an attempt to generalise the concept. You have to keep in mind that acoustics is a field treating mechanical waves from a macroscopic point of view (not always true but quite true for most applications). Thus in many common applications (such as the determination of absorption coefficients), the interest lies in acquiring values for objects or describing bigger systems without going through the details of modelling every part of it.